# Where to store nationalities array in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a user object that has a `nationality` column which is a string. A user upon sign-up is able to pick their nationality via a dropdown. I'm wondering where should I store this `NATIONALITIES` constant, seeing that i'll be a huge array of strings.

Comment: You might consider looking into the [country_select gem](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select)

Answer (score 2):

You should have a database table named as `countries`. You can use this table for populating `nationalities` dropdown.

Update datatype of `nationality` column of `users` table from String to Integer. When user will select a country, add the corresponding `id` into `nationality` column.

Comment: Is it necessary that I make a new table for countries? I'll only be used as a string in the user model. Also, the countries will remain fairly constant for a long time, so I don't see the point of editing it often.

Comment: It will be reusable in other models if necessary. I would suggest and index on this new integer column if you planned finding your users by nationalities.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an array of constant strings for nationality, there is no need for creating a model.

Try [Nationality Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/nationality). It is easy as calling *Nationality*::NATIONALITY.